# How do I use ui-sref-active with bootstrap navbar-brand?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, navbar

In this sample: [Angularjs navigation menu with UI-Bootstrap tabs and UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693320/angularjs-navigation-menu-with-ui-bootstrap-tabs-and-ui-router/29937880#29937880)

The following works great for the list items on the navbar and highlights them as I click:

```
 <ul>
   <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
     <a href ui-sref="route1">route1</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

But when I use the standard boostrap navbar-brand  I can't make this work:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ui-sref-active="active" class="navbar-header">
            <a href class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="state1">State1</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
                <a href ui-sref="state2">State2</a>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
                <a href ui-sref="state3">State3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

Have tried just about everything, but can't find this specific combination of technologies and the navbar-brand.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the undesired behaviour?

Comment: The navbar-brand on the far left doesn't highlight.

Comment: Please include a jsfiddle or something similar